# variable = None in Python? What does it mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to coding. I saw some code where variable = None, what does it mean? I can't find an answer anywhere online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well what do you think it means...?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None

Comment: +1 since this came up before the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sets a variable named `variable` to [`None`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html) (Python's version of a null/nonetype object).

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> variable = None
>>> type(variable)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

---

I really think you should read one of the many Python tutorials out there since this is a fundamental language concept.  Here are some I found useful:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards tutorials, but what is the difference between setting variable to 0 versus setting it to None?

Comment: @verkter - It depends on the program.  You are right in saying that, in a lot of areas, the two can be used interchangeably (since each evaluate to `False`).  However, there are some instances when you need a nonetype/null object and `0` will not suffice.  An example is with the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the value `None` to the variable `variable`. I recommend you read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/); it will answer this question and many more.